# Nancy Slow On Mono (using OWIN SelfHost)

Tags: c#, mono, raspberry-pi, nancy

I'm trying desperately to figure out why all of my requests seem to have about 1.5 seconds added to them. I have logged times between when the route is hit to when the response is returned and that always seems to be less that 100 ms. The Request container takes less than 10ms to configure as well.

I have no other pipelines in my own application. I did some profiling while running the application and here are some of the method calls that consume the most time. I can show more information, but the logs are pretty lengthy, so I'll keep it to this for now:

```
    Method call summary
Total(ms) Self(ms)      Calls Method name
  377145        0          1 (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>:runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
  377145        7          1 HobbyQuarters.Web.Program:Main (string[])
  315511        2          1 Mono.Unix.UnixSignal:WaitAny (Mono.Unix.UnixSignal[])
  315509        0          1 Mono.Unix.UnixSignal:WaitAny (Mono.Unix.UnixSignal[],int)
  315508   315504          1 (wrapper managed-to-native) Mono.Unix.UnixSignal:WaitAny (intptr[],int,int,Mono.Unix.UnixSignal/Mono_Posix_RuntimeIsShuttingDown)
   61408        0          1 Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp:Start (string,System.Action`1<Owin.IAppBuilder>)
   61369        3          1 Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp:Start (Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.StartOptions,System.Action`1<Owin.IAppBuilder>)
   61239        7          1 Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp:StartImplementation (System.IServiceProvider,Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.StartOptions,System.Action`1<Owin.IAppBuilder>)
   58935       23         32 System.Threading.ExecutionContext:Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool)
   58911       67         32 System.Threading.ExecutionContext:RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool)
   58315       16          1 Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.HostingEngine:Start (Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.StartContext)
   57391        3          1 Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.HostingEngine:ResolveApp (Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.StartContext)
   56891        1          1 HobbyQuarters.Web.Program/<Main>c__AnonStorey0:<>m__0 (Owin.IAppBuilder)
   56866       10          1 Owin.AppBuilderExtensions:UseNancy (Owin.IAppBuilder,System.Action`1<Nancy.Owin.NancyOptions>)
   54087        1        135 (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>:runtime_invoke_bool (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
   54085        3        134 System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback:PerformWaitCallback ()
   54082        9        134 System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue:Dispatch ()
   53886        5         37 System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback:System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem ()
   53732        3          1 Owin.AppBuilderExtensions:UseNancy (Owin.IAppBuilder,Nancy.Owin.NancyOptions)
   53709        8          1 Nancy.Owin.NancyMiddleware:UseNancy (Nancy.Owin.NancyOptions)
   52888        9         16 Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.OwinHttpListener/<ProcessRequestsAsync>d__0:MoveNext ()
   52870        5        139 System.Threading.Tasks.Task:FinishStageThree ()
   52869        1          8 System.Net.ListenerAsyncResult:InvokeCallback (object)
   52867        3          8 System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1/<FromAsyncImpl>c__AnonStorey1<TResult_REF>:<>m__0 (System.IAsyncResult)
   52867        3        115 System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<TResult_REF>:TrySetResult (TResult_REF)
   52864        4        139 System.Threading.Tasks.Task:FinishContinuations ()
   52863        2          8 System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1<TResult_REF>:FromAsyncCoreLogic (System.IAsyncResult,System.Func`2<System.IAsyncResult, TResult_REF>,System.Action`1<System.IAsyncResult>,System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<TResult_REF>,bool)
   52855        1          8 System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation:RunOrScheduleAction (System.Action,bool,System.Threading.Tasks.Task&)
   52852        0          8 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore/MoveNextRunner:Run ()
   52851        0          8 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore/MoveNextRunner:InvokeMoveNext (object)
   52835        4          8 Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.OwinHttpListener:ProcessRequestAsync (System.Net.HttpListenerContext)
   52815        5          8 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder:Start<Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.OwinHttpListener/<ProcessRequestAsync>d__5> (Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.OwinHttpListener/<ProcessRequestAsync>d__5&)
   52808        9          8 Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.OwinHttpListener/<ProcessRequestAsync>d__5:MoveNext ()
   52621        3          8 Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Utilities.Encapsulate:Invoke (System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2<string, object>)
   52594        4          8 Microsoft.Owin.Infrastructure.OwinMiddlewareTransition:Invoke (System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2<string, object>)
   52561        7          8 Microsoft.Owin.Infrastructure.AppFuncTransition:Invoke (Microsoft.Owin.IOwinContext)
   52553       19          8 Nancy.Owin.NancyMiddleware/<>c__DisplayClass4/<>c__DisplayClass6:<UseNancy>b__1 (System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2<string, object>)
   52403        4          8 Nancy.NancyEngineExtensions:HandleRequest (Nancy.INancyEngine,Nancy.Request,System.Func`2<Nancy.NancyContext, Nancy.NancyContext>,System.Action`1<Nancy.NancyContext>,System.Action`1<System.Exception>,System.Threading.CancellationToken)
   51297       11          8 Nancy.NancyEngine:HandleRequest (Nancy.Request,System.Func`2<Nancy.NancyContext, Nancy.NancyContext>,System.Threading.CancellationToken)
   48567        2         15 Ninject.Modules.AssemblyNameRetriever:GetAssemblyNames (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<string>,System.Predicate`1<System.Reflection.Assembly>)
   47752       15         56 Nancy.Helpers.TaskHelpers:WhenCompleted<T_REF> (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<T_REF>,System.Action`1<System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<T_REF>>,System.Action`1<System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<T_REF>>,bool)
   44890       61          1 Nancy.Bootstrapper.NancyBootstrapperBase`1<TContainer_REF>:Initialise ()
   43596        5        247 Ninject.KernelBase/<>c__DisplayClass15:<Resolve>b__f (Ninject.Planning.Bindings.IBinding)
   43133        8        247 Ninject.Activation.Context:Resolve ()
   43094       56        247 Ninject.Activation.Context:ResolveInternal (object)
   42379       20        127 Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider:Create (Ninject.Activation.IContext)
   41979      100       3302 System.Linq.Enumerable/WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2<TSource_REF, TResult_REF>:MoveNext ()
   36906        4         15 Ninject.Modules.AssemblyNameRetriever:CreateTemporaryAppDomain ()
   36813        6         15 System.AppDomain:CreateDomain (string,System.Security.Policy.Evidence,System.AppDomainSetup)
   35717      134        489 (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
   34389       14         10 Ninject.KernelBase:.ctor (Ninject.Components.IComponentContainer,Ninject.INinjectSettings,Ninject.Modules.INinjectModule[])
   34238        5         10 Ninject.KernelBase:Load (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<string>)
   34188       14         10 Ninject.Modules.ModuleLoader:LoadModules (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<string>)
   34177      199       4529 System.Linq.Buffer`1<TElement_REF>:.ctor (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<TElement_REF>)
   34026        5         10 Ninject.Modules.CompiledModuleLoaderPlugin:LoadModules (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<string>)
   33839       30       3889 System.Linq.Enumerable:ToArray<TSource_REF> (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<TSource_REF>)
   32142       62       4564 System.Linq.Enumerable/WhereSelectArrayIterator`2<TSource_REF, TResult_REF>:MoveNext ()
   31210       21         17 Nancy.Bootstrapper.NancyBootstrapperWithRequestContainerBase`1<TContainer_REF>:GetConfiguredRequestContainer (Nancy.NancyContext)
   30087        7          5 System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates:UpdateAndExecute2<T0_REF, T1_REF, TRet_REF> (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,T0_REF,T1_REF)
   29806        1          9 Nancy.Bootstrappers.Ninject.NinjectNancyBootstrapper:CreateRequestContainer (Nancy.NancyContext)
   29803        0          9 Ninject.Extensions.ChildKernel.ChildKernel:.ctor (Ninject.Syntax.IResolutionRoot,Ninject.INinjectSettings,Ninject.Modules.INinjectModule[])
   29803        0          9 Ninject.StandardKernel:.ctor (Ninject.INinjectSettings,Ninject.Modules.INinjectModule[])
   29802        0          9 Ninject.KernelBase:.ctor (Ninject.INinjectSettings,Ninject.Modules.INinjectModule[])
   29610        3        222 Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider/<>c__DisplayClass4:<Create>b__2 (Ninject.Planning.Targets.ITarget)
   29607      135        222 Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider:GetValue (Ninject.Activation.IContext,Ninject.Planning.Targets.ITarget)
   29429        7        175 Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1<T_REF>:ResolveWithin (Ninject.Activation.IContext)
   29301        4        156 Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1<T_REF>:GetValue (System.Type,Ninject.Activation.IContext)
   28844        7        410 System.Linq.Enumerable:SingleOrDefault<TSource_REF> (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<TSource_REF>)
```

Also, here is the startup file if interested:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string baseUrl = args[0];
        string rootDir = args[1];

        var server = WebApp.Start(baseUrl, (appBuilder) =>
        {
            appBuilder
            .Use(typeof(RequestMiddleware))
            .UseNancy(x =>
            {
                x.Bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper(rootDir);
                x.PerformPassThrough = p =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Passthrough Start: {0}", DateTime.Now.Ticks);

                    return
                    p.Request.Headers.Any(h => h.Key == "Repository") ||
                    !p.Request.Path.StartsWith("/achillescr/api");
                };
            });
        });

        using (server)
        {
            if (Type.GetType("Mono.Runtime") != null)
            {
                // on mono, processes will usually run as daemons - this allows you to listen
                // for termination signals (ctrl+c, shutdown, etc) and finalize correctly
                UnixSignal.WaitAny(new[] {
                new UnixSignal(Signum.SIGINT),
                new UnixSignal(Signum.SIGTERM),
                new UnixSignal(Signum.SIGQUIT),
                new UnixSignal(Signum.SIGHUP)
            });
            }
            else
            {
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Stopping AchillesCR");
        }
    }
```

Also, here is the version of Mono:

```
Mono JIT compiler version 4.4.1 (Nightly 4.4.1.0/4747417 Wed Jun 22 11:38:12 UTC)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           _thread
        SIGSEGV:       normal
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  armel,vpf+hard
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          softdebug
        LLVM:          supported, not enabled
        GC:            sgen
```

Comment: Slow? Compared to what? Nancy/Mono are not optimized like Microsoft's stack, and also the hardware is crappy. I really don't think the numbers are "slow", and I think it is doomed .

Comment: what version of mono are you using?

Comment: @LexLi I would assume that if the JSON is being creating within about 200 ms then it wouldn't take Nancy/Owin an extra second to send that information, seems odd to me that that might be the case. I set up a reverse proxy using nginx and that seemed to have helped shave off a quarter of a second, but 1.5 seconds for a simple request still seems a bit slow even for this stack. Do you think it could be something on the networking level?

Comment: @knoct I've added the information about mono to the post, basically its 4.4.1

Comment: @ThePaxBisonica did you measure the average time for N requests? the 1st request is always slower than the rest

Comment: I waited until after the first request to see how long it was taking

Comment: I noticed the same thing that the same Nancy app running on the same machine is significantly faster on Windows than on Debian via Mono. For example when I run a load test I have an avg response time of < 5ms on Windows and > 50ms on Debian/Mono. That is a massive degradation and I am also running out of ideas where the time is lost. Have you found anything since you posted this question?

Comment: to be honest no, I made a few tweeks to the nginx server running it which helped, but that was basically it. It looks like it spends a lot of time switching contexts so I'm going to try and avoid async calls unless they are really needed

Comment: also, I was using a raspberry pi and am now switching to a latte panda as that has offered much better performance for this; although, I'm still interested in optimizing this to work on the pi.. I'll let you know if I find anything else